# Escape character in C#'s Split()

Tags: c#, string, split, escaping

I am parsing some delimiter separated values, where `?` is specified as the escape character in case the delimiter appears as part of one of the values.

For instance: if `:` is the delimiter, and a certain field the value `19:30`, this needs to be written as `19?:30`.

Currently, I use `string[] values = input.Split(':');` in order to get an array of all values, but after learning about this escape character, this won't work anymore.

Is there a way to make `Split` take escape characters into account? I have checked the overload methods, and there does not seem to be such an option directly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string[] substrings = Regex.Split("aa:bb:00?:99:zz", @"(?<!\?):");
```

for

```
aa
bb
00?:99
zz
```

Or as you probably want to unescape ?: at some point, replace the sequence in the input with another token, split and replace back.

(This requires the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace to be used.)

Comment: What about `aa:bb:00??:99:zz`?

Comment: You would get `"00??:9"` which seems ok as there is no splitalbe token

Comment: ...unless you treat `??` as "escape of escape".

Comment: it depends, if we assume **?** is acting like \ in C then the result should be `00??` and `9`.

Comment: Serg makes a great point, but as far as I can tell from my specifications, escape characters never get escaped. It seems like they deliberately picked `?` because they know that it will never appear as part of a value.

Comment: @LeeWhite  If `?` can never appear as part of a value, it would be far better to use _it_ as the field delimiter, because you wouldn't need to worry about escaping -- or is it too late to do this?

Comment: @TripeHound Fair point, but even if this *could* be changed, I would not be in a position to have influence over this.

Comment: In that case, assuming no `::` appear you could use the vanilla split; `foo.Replace(':', '?').Replace("??", ":").Split(new[] { '?' });`

Comment: @AlexK.: I just found out that there is a problem with the solution you gave. When the escape character does *not* occur, and `@"[^?]:"` is matched, **the character prior to the delimiter is removed from the value**. I'm guessing this is because the character matches `[^?]`, hence is part of the split characters sequence. Do you happen to know a nice way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of this text?

Comment: Your example, for instance. It returns `{"a", "b", "00?:9", "zz"}`.

Comment: Woops missed that, updated with a negative look-behind instead

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff is always fun to code without using *Regex*.

The following does the trick with one single caveat: the escape character will *always* escape, it has no logic to check for only *valid* ones: `?;`. So the string `one?two;three??;four?;five` will be split into `onewo`, `three?`, `fourfive`.

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string text, char separator, char escapeCharacter, bool removeEmptyEntries)
 {
     string buffer = string.Empty;
     bool escape = false;

     foreach (var c in text)
     {
         if (!escape && c == separator)
         {
             if (!removeEmptyEntries || buffer.Length > 0)
             {
                 yield return buffer;
             }

             buffer = string.Empty;
         }
         else
         {
             if (c == escapeCharacter)
             {
                 escape = !escape;

                 if (!escape)
                 {
                     buffer = string.Concat(buffer, c);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 if (!escape)
                 {
                     buffer = string.Concat(buffer, c);
                 }

                 escape = false;
             }
         }
     }

        if (buffer.Length != 0)
        {
            yield return buffer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And also usually incorrect. `buffer` should be `StringBuilder` in order not to create loads of temporary `string` instances, and `?:` should append `:` instead of ignoring it, and empty substrings are treated incorrectly.

Answer (score -2):

No, there's no way to do that. You will need to use regex (which depends on how exactly do you want your "escape character" to behave). In worst case I suppose you'll have to do the parsing manually.

Comment: you can comment with 4k rep. or give an answer.